# C++ Int Function with Parameters long unwanted error message

Tags: c++, memory

This piece of code is from the C++ Primer Plus book. I have copied down the code from the book (except for a few comments to make my code neater). When I run it, however, it gives me a long error message. I am using the MinGW compiler and using powershell to run my code. Here it is:

```
//convert.cpp -- converts stone to pounds

Libraries
#include <iostream>

//Namespaces
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

//Function Prototypes
int stonetolb(int sts); 

//Main Function
int main()
{
    int stone;
    cout << "Enter the weight in stone: ";
    cin >> stone;
    int pounds = stonetolb(stone);
    cout << stone << " stone ";
    cout << pounds << " pounds." << endl;
    return 0;
}

//Functions
int stonetolb(int sts)
{
    return 14 * sts;
}
```

There is one more comment showing the location of my file (to make it more convenient while using powershell), but I have left it out for security purposes.

The error is hundreds of lines long, so I'll just share the first part. Here it is  (it's in code blocks to make it easier for you to read) :

```
from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ostream:38,
from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/iostream:39,
from convert.cpp:4:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:181:33: error: '__i' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '__s'?
  181 |       for (std::size_t __i = 0; __i < __n; ++__i)
      |                                 ^~~
      |                                 __s
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h: At global scope:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:191:50: error: 'std::size_t' has not been declared
  191 |     move(char_type* __s1, const char_type* __s2, std::size_t __n)
      |                                                  ^~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:213:50: error: 'std::size_t' has not been declared
  213 |     copy(char_type* __s1, const char_type* __s2, std::size_t __n)
      |                                                  ^~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:224:28: error: 'std::size_t' has not been declared
  224 |     assign(char_type* __s, std::size_t __n, char_type __a)
      |                            ^~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function 'static constexpr size_t std::char_traits<char>::length(const char_type*)':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:369:53: error: 'length' is not a member of '__gnu_cxx::char_traits<char>'
  369 |           return __gnu_cxx::char_traits<char_type>::length(__s);
      |                                                     ^~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function 'static constexpr size_t std::char_traits<wchar_t>::length(const char_type*)':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:493:53: error: 'length' is not a member of '__gnu_cxx::char_traits<wchar_t>'
  493 |           return __gnu_cxx::char_traits<char_type>::length(__s);
      |                                                     ^~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:495:22: error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'size_t wcslen(const wchar_t*)'
  495 |         return wcslen(__s);
      |                ~~~~~~^~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/cwchar:44,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/iosfwd:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ios:38,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from convert.cpp:4:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wchar.h:1328:18: note: 'size_t wcslen(const wchar_t*)' declared here
 1328 |   size_t __cdecl wcslen(const wchar_t *_Str);
      |                  ^~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/string:41,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ios:42,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from convert.cpp:4:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h: At global scope:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:59:20: error: 'size_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   59 |       typedef std::size_t     size_type;
      |                    ^~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:60:20: error: 'ptrdiff_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   60 |       typedef std::ptrdiff_t  difference_type;
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:103:16: error: 'size_type' has not been declared
  103 |       allocate(size_type __n, const void* = static_cast<const void*>(0))
      |                ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:132:28: error: 'size_type' has not been declared
  132 |       deallocate(_Tp* __p, size_type __t __attribute__ ((__unused__)))
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:153:7: error: 'size_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'size_t'?
  153 |       size_type
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
      |       size_t
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:196:26: error: 'size_type' does not name a type; did you mean 'size_t'?
  196 |       _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR size_type
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~
      |                          size_t
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h: In member function '_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::allocate(int, const void*)':
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/new_allocator.h:115:29: error: 'size_t' is not a member of 'std'; did you mean 'size_t'?
  115 |             if (__n > (std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(_Tp)))
      |                             ^~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wchar.h:9,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/cwchar:44,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/iosfwd:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ios:38,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from convert.cpp:4:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/corecrt.h:35:44: note: 'size_t' declared here
   35 | __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef unsigned __int64 size_t;
      |                                            ^~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h:34,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/string:55,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ios:42,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from convert.cpp:4:
```

This is about 1/50th of the entire error message.

Comment: That line that says `Libraries` doesn't belong there. That could be what's confusing the compiler.

Comment: That series of error messages is certainly long-winded. The thing is, it's a bunch of error messages, one after another. That can be daunting, but the key, usually, is to only pay attention to the first error. The text starts off with three lines that begin with "from"; that gives you context. The fourth line has "error:", and that's the description of the first error.

Comment: [Your code will compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c665d61eb0e33be).  It seems like your issue is your compiler.  Something is not set up correctly.

Comment: Did you really type `Libraries` instead of `//Libraries`? I am not sure because I get and would expect different errors: [https://ideone.com/0iUQXF](https://ideone.com/0iUQXF)

Comment: If you look at first error it says it has some problem with `char_traits.h` , maybe you need some compiler flag like `-std=c++17`

Comment: @drescherjm yes! I added the comment slashes and it worked. I don't understand why there was such a long error message and the compiler didn't just give which line the error was on, but it's fine. Thank you so much.